# CSS Compatibility on IE. Box shadows

Tags: css, internet-explorer, background, border

I'm creating a website and I need to style some boxes like this [image here](http://rookery9.aviary.com.s3.amazonaws.com/4614500/4614512_22a2_rss.jpg). Although, their height aren't fixed for it's dynamic content I used `-webkit-border-image`and `-moz-image-border`and it worked perfectly. Unfortunately, IE is a bad bad guy and I wanted it to appear properly.

I thought about using CSS3 with `box-shadow` and `-webkit-gradient` and `-moz-linear-gradient` but again IE doesn't work.

I'd like to know some CSS technique so that I can have the gradient box and the shadows within a `div` with undefined size (I mean dynamic height and width)

Comment: moz etc is a firefox style and will only work in firebug or browsers with that kit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here is the possible solution :)](http://fetchak.com/ie-css3/)

Comment: @Rodrigo Alves: Yes it could be so, check the docs. Try putting htc file in the root.

Comment: I found out. The problem is that i'm also using the `filter` property for gradient. It fills up the whole div and the rounded corner stays behind the gradient. How can I use gradient and rounded corner?

Answer (score 0):

If the width is fixed, and the background is homogenous, this will work even on IE6:

1. Take the picture, cut out the middle gradient/white, make it transparent (the shadows should remain opaque), grey to white. Cut it into 2 pieces - the top part which can be stretched to any height without change to looks, and the bottom part with rounded corners (bg-mid.png and bg-bottom.png)
2. The top gradient part is also cut as a high, 1 pixel wide image.
3. Write this HTML code:

> ```
> <div class="gradient-bg">
>     <div class="top-content">
>         your content
>     </div>
>     <div class="bottom-shadow">
>     </div>
> </div>
> ```

Then, style them accordingly. Place the gradient image as the top div Background, the bg-mid.png as the top-content background (with repeat-x), and the bottom shadow - that's bg-bottom.png.

For IE6 you'll need to use [conditional CSS statements, and filter CSS attribute](http://alexandermp.com/post/2010/07/06/How-to-make-pages-compatible-with-Internet-Explorer-6.aspx) to load images with alpha channel.